# Definition of ordinary derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

My textbook has this definition for an ODE: 
If a differential equation contains only ordinary de-
rivatives of one or more unknown functions with respect to a single independent
variable, it is said to be an ordinary differential equation (ODE).

I cannot for the life of me find a clear definition for the construct "ordinary derivative". I assume this is important because it is one of two qualifiers in the statement which is defining the ODE. I cant be the only person to have ever searched this and yet my google foo is failing me. Super grateful for any help here, explanation or reference. A reference would be fantastic since i suspect this may just be an issue of hand waving in the definition and perhaps i should get a more rigorous textbook but i dont know what to buy. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

"Ordinary" just means "not partial" (as in "partial derivative"), and in this context is wholly redundant with the phrase "with respect to a single independent variable".  In other words, our function is a function of **one** (real) variable, and we can differentiate it with respect to that variable any number of times and write an equation relating those derivatives and the original function.  This is in contrast with a partial differential equation, where we have a function of more than one real variable and can have an equation relating its partial derivatives with respect to the different variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can move on!

Comment: Isn't "total" the term that means "not partial"?  Is "ordinary derivative" synonymous with "total derivative"?

Comment: @Maxpm: No.  "Total derivative" normally instead refers to the derivative of a function of multiple variables with respect to all variables at once, considered as a higher-dimensional linear map (which contains all the partial derivatives as matrix components).